# Foundation Button Change Color

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm using foundation 5 and I'm trying to change the background color for the active button

```
<li class="active">
```

And the background color for the normal buttons upon hover in the top-bar. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with foundation but can't you just use CSS to override? CSS: `.active {background-color: #eee !important;}`

Comment: Kevin, what's the point of your answer?

Comment: @CiaranBaselmans I've tried with a simple .active and a .top-bar-section active {}. None worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the top-bar CSS, search the foundation CSS file for **active**.
 You should come across this code:

```
.top-bar-section ul li.active > a {
    background: #008cba;
    color: white; }
    .top-bar-section ul li.active > a:hover {
      background: #0079a1; }
```

Change the background to your desired colour. 
Regarding the CSS of the active button, can you be a little more specific as to what button you mean?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Clear and to the point. I just wanted the active Home button for example to have a different background color. I won't use active for another thing, so your answer is just what I needed.

Comment: Do you have any idea what class is used to style regular top-bar buttons? I'd like to add a hover color to those as well.

Comment: Search the file for `.top-bar-section ul li`. You will come across the CSS for `.top-bar-section ul li > a` and `.top-bar-section ul li > a.button ` among many others all grouped together in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Try following css

```
li.active{

    background-color:red !important;
}
li.active:hover{

    background-color:yellow !important;
}
```

look at the working example at < http://jsfiddle.net/jspatel/2weCW/1/>

Comment: This would work in a normal situation, but Foundation uses it's own css file for basic styling and arrangement. After that, you are supposed to include your own css file in which you make modifications. I tried that piece of code, but it didn't work. http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/topbar.html

Comment: ok i changed the code above a bit..  try adding  !important after each line, this would overwrite your foundation css.